# I'm moving jar file to other PC then the program not showing image

Tags: java

I finished my project and done the compilation. Running the Jar file, program is working.
If I'm moving jar file to other PC then the program is not showing image and not showing information from txt files.
I thinking this is from wrong paths. Can you help me?
This some code:

```
FileInputStream fr2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Nickolskiy\\IdeaProjects\\DeutcheCard\\src\\com\\2.txt");
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(fr2, "Cp1251"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The first line you gave is referring to an absolute file path. If the target machine does not have a file at that exact file location, it will not be able to open the file.

Because the file is located in the `src` directory, it will be packaged into the JAR. You can then use a different API to get a resource inside a JAR file, which looks like this:

```
/*
 * /com/ because the file is located in the com package
 */
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/2.txt");
```

That way, your code will stay portable.

Also, because you are not saying you got a stack trace, I suspect you have code like this:

```
try
{
    // Perform I/O actions
} catch (IOException ioe)
{
}
```

The empty catch block will cause all errors to be discarded. At least put a `ioe.printStackTrace()` in there to get the stack trace!

Another reason might be that you are not running the JAR file from a terminal. If you run the jar file with `java -jar thejarfile.jar`, you will be able to see when something gets printed out.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an absolute path. You will get an FileNotFound-Exception, unless the other PC is using the same path. (C:\Users\Nickolskiy ...). Try to use a relative path.